# How to login by cookie with Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security

In my Spring Boot application, user information is encoded and stored in cookies. For every request the user sends, server just needs to parse cookie. If success, server extracts user info and let the request pass. How can I implement this procedure in Spring Security by implementing a custom authentication procedure?

I'm trying to switch from Shiro to Spring Security.

Comment: @fabienbk Thanks, but I need to handle login request by my own instead of the framework

Comment: @fabienbk I've read this post. Custom `AuthenticationProvider` isn't enough because I can't get cookies from `AuthenticationProdiver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a sub class of [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html):

> Abstract processor of browser-based HTTP-based authentication requests.

and add this class to the filter chain, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-custom-filters):

> You can add your own filter to the stack, using the `custom-filter` element and one of these names to specify the position your filter should appear at:
>
> ```
> <http>
>     <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
> </http>
>
> <beans:bean id="myFilter" class="com.mycompany.MySpecialAuthenticationFilter"/>
> ```